# Javascript Onready function to call the Namespace function

Tags: javascript, namespaces, onready

i am removing the global variables in the Javascript that is used in my Rails/views/show.html.erb

The javascript that i am using is

```
var App = {};
App.UserSnapShot = function () {
  var _body, _detailEl, _selectedLinkEl;

  var _init = function () {
    _body = $$("body")[0];

    $$(".user-link").each(function (el) {
      el.observe("mouseover", function (event) {
        _selectedLinkEl = el;
        _detailEl = event.element().next();
        _detailEl.show();
        _body.observe("mouseover", _bodyMouseOverFunction);
      });
    });
  };

  var _bodyMouseOverFunction = function (event) {
    if (event.element() != _selectedLinkEl && 
        event.element() != _detailEl && 
        !event.element().ancestors().include(_detailEl)) {
      _detailEl.hide();
      _body.stopObserving("mouseover", _bodyMouseOverFunction);
    }
  };

  return {
    init: function () {
      _init();
    }
  };
}();
```

I need to call my function App.UserSnapShot.init();through onready function of the same .. , So that to get this to work ..
             How can i add a onReady function here.

Pls give some suggestions

Comment: ALL THOSE UNDERSCORES!! AAAAAAHHHHHHHH!!!!!

Comment: @jacob for private varaible i gave _variablename

Comment: what do you mean by `onready function of the same`? Please explain what you want in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean?

```
App.onReady = function() {
    App.UserSnapShot.init();
};

document.observe("dom:loaded", App.onReady);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery...

$(document).ready(function(){
// Insert code to run on document load here
});